# R - obscure ggplot2 error:

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have created a grouped data frame using dplyr:

```
average_steps.i2 <- activity2 %>% 
   group_by(Group, interval) %>%
   summarise(Average.Steps = mean(steps))
```

when I attempt to plot it, using ggplot

```
ggplot(average_steps.i2 , aes(x=date,y=Average.Steps)) + 
      geom_line() +
      facet_wrap(~Group , nrow=2)
```

I get the following error:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous
Error in data.frame(x = function ()  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 576
```

What does this mean? (I can program around by creating separate data sets and using par() to stack them, but would like to know the ggplot way to do this)

Comment: There is no column `date` in your `average_steps.i2` data.frame.

Comment: @user3674944: Could you provide your dataset or did the comment by LyzandeR solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks. I'm on the road, but that looks like it.